# How to "fix" the slide function in jquery

Tags: jquery, slide

I have run into a problem with jquerys native slide function, i really like what it does and everything, but for some reason it seems to count the amount of times you hover over it (when you use the `.hover` as aposed to determining if you are still hovered over it. for instance: [live demo](http://jsbin.com/oyower/2/edit). you will notice that if you hover over, remove, then hover over again in quick succession, there will be an issue with what seems to be lag time, does anyone know a way to resolve this? I cant seem to find anything that specifically adresses this issue.

heres the code, for those to skeptic to click on the link, or something:

html:

```
<div id="click">
    <div id="box"></div>
</div>
```

css:

```
  #box { 
    background:#de9a44;
    width:80px; 
    height:60px; 
    display:none; 
    position:absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

#click {
    width:80px; 
    height:60px; 
    border:1px solid #cc0001; 
    background:transparent; 
    position:absolute; 
    top:0; 
}
```

jquery:

```
$("#click").hover(function () {
    $("#box").slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/stop/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this:

```
$("#click").hover(function () {
    $("#box").stop().slideToggle("slow");
});
```

Comment: Exactly what I was going to post.
You're facing queue buildup, @Nick
.stop() will tell it to "Whoa! Stop piling on the animation. Stop where you are, and now get ready to do... something else".

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, the mechanics behind jquery are still a tad new to me

Comment: you're welcome, I actually didn't expect that to work aswell as it did!